# why is ggplot outputting data in this way?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can anyone please explain why the y axis on my graph looks weird? For example it's putting 57,368 above 64,157 for the x axis value 1. It seems like it has created two graphs and and then appeneded them.

```
my_df

X1    X2
1 64157
2 49183
3 51234
4 46463
5 42790
6 39768
7 40726
8 40199
9 37142
10 44442
11 43982
12 41541
1 57368
2 47766
3 48664
4 39101
5 44279
6 42175
7 38425
8 41074
9 40095
10 43597
11 45580
12 45129

ggplot(my_df, aes(x = X1,
                    y = X2 )) + geom_point()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: This is the alphabetical order. That's because your column `X1` is not numeric (it is in character mode or it is a factor).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, your concern is about the y-values, not about the x-axis. But you have two rows with `X1=1`, then it's normal to have two y-values here (even if `X1` were numeric).

Comment: Try `my_df[] <- lapply(my_df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. I hadn't considered the variable type as a possible issue. I've now tried changing the factored columns to numeric and integer both of which resolve the problem. Thanks. :o)